# 24V Car accessory fan into a normal car socket

Tags: car, fan, socket

From my online "research", I've learnt that a car socket is 12V and can is capable of 180W.

But I bought a car fan that is rated to run 24V 0.4A and 10W.

Is it safe for me to plug in into the car socket?

Thank you.

Comment: It will not do what you bought it to do, no. Send it back, get the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

A 24 volt motor will likely run at half it’s designed speed when running on 12 volts, so it probably isn’t even worth plugging it in.

It is more than likely safe to plug it in, but because we don’t know how it is constructed it is impossible to say.